# how to re-enable all extensions in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently disabled all extensions on VS CODE due to extension host exceptions.  This solved the initial problem, but now I want to re-enable them (one-at-a-time or all-at-once) to try to identify the one causing the exception.

Unfortunately, **ALL** menu selections having to do with enabling extensions are disabled (grayed out) including sub-menus associated with each individual extension and the "Enable all extensions" from the More (***) menu.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks,
Don

P.S. I'm using VS CODE 1.24.1 on Linux Mint 18.3.

Answer (score 6):

After hours of googling, searching SO, etc.,  I finally found out how to remove all extensions from *VS CODE.*  On linux, go to ~/.vscode, then rename (mv) the **extensions** folder.  *(There is an equivalent folder in Windows: `%USERPROFILE%/.vscode/extensions`).*  Restart VS Code and all extensions are gone!

Now I can re-install them one-by-one and see which one(s) cause the extension host exception.

Don

Comment: Thanks -- simple and effective!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem today and try to check out on google only to find out that there is no currently solution.

However, i tried to scan through all the functionality under the extension menu, and fortunately, i came across **enable all extension**

And here is the solution; On the left menu of the vscode, or use shortcut key: ctrl + shift + x, then locate a ... button at the top edge (in front of Extension), click the button and select enable all extension.

If it looks like nothing changed, restart VScode.